# combining sparkline in kableExtra table

Tags: r, sparklines, kableextra, formattable

I am trying to create a table with subheadings and sparklines.

I am able to create the table with subheading with the `kableExtra` package. And I am able to create a table with sparklines with the `formattable` and `sparkline` package.

However, I am not able to combine both. Is there way?
I saw [this](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/use_kableExtra_with_formattable.html), but didn't help me.

```
library(sparkline)
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          V1 = c("country", "A", "B", "C"),
          V2 = c(2000L, 100L, 600L, 50L),
          V3 = c(2001L, 200L, 500L, 60L),
          V4 = c(2002L, 300L, 400L, 70L),
          V5 = c(2003L, 400L, 300L, 80L),
          V6 = c(2004L, 500L, 200L, 90L),
          V7 = c(2005L, 600L, 100L, 100L)
)

df.names <- df[1,]
names(df) <- df.names
df <- df[-1,]

graph <- df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  gather(key=year, value=value, -country) %>% 
  summarise(graph=spk_chr(
    value, 
    chartRangeMin = 0,
    type="line"))

df2 <- left_join(df, graph, by=c("country"))


df2 %>%
  formattable::formattable(align=c("l")) %>% 
  as.htmlwidget() %>% 
  spk_add_deps()
```

[image]

```
df2 %>%
  kable("html", caption="Title", escape=T) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  group_rows("group1", 1, 2) %>%
  group_rows("group2", 3,3)
```

[image]

```
df2 %>%
  kable("html", caption="Title", escape=T) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  group_rows("group1", 1, 2) %>%
  group_rows("group2", 3,3) %>% 
  formattable::formattable(align=c("l")) %>% 
  as.htmlwidget() %>% 
  spk_add_deps()
```

Creates error:

```
Error in create_obj(x, "formattable", list(formatter = formatter, format = list(...),  : 
  argument "formatter" is missing, with no default
```

Note that I tried both `kable("html", caption="Title", escape=TRUE) and escape=FALSE`

Comment: I had some issues with trying to get sparklines working with kableExtra as well - if I tried ```df2 %>%
    kable("html", caption="Title", escape=T) %>% 
    kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
    group_rows("group1", 1, 2) %>%
    group_rows("group2", 3,3) %>% 
    as.htmlwidget() %>% 
    spk_add_deps()```, ignoring the formattable function, I get ```Error in UseMethod("as.htmlwidget") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.htmlwidget' applied to an object of class "c('kableExtra', 'knitr_kable')"```

Comment: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/336

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem. This fixed it for me:

```
library(sparkline)
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)
library(kableExtra)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             V1 = c("country", "A", "B", "C"),
             V2 = c(2000L, 100L, 600L, 50L),
             V3 = c(2001L, 200L, 500L, 60L),
             V4 = c(2002L, 300L, 400L, 70L),
             V5 = c(2003L, 400L, 300L, 80L),
             V6 = c(2004L, 500L, 200L, 90L),
             V7 = c(2005L, 600L, 100L, 100L)
)

df.names <- df[1,]
names(df) <- df.names
df <- df[-1,]

graph <- df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  gather(key=year, value=value, -country) %>% 
  summarise(graph=spk_chr(
    value, 
    chartRangeMin = 0,
    type="line"))

df2 <- left_join(df, graph, by=c("country"))

df2 %>%
formattable::format_table(
  x = .,
  formatters = list(
    align=c("l")
  )
) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  group_rows("group1", 1, 2) %>%
  group_rows("group2", 3,3) %>%
  htmltools::HTML() %>%
  shiny::div() %>%
  sparkline::spk_add_deps()
```

The solution is that `formattable::format_table()` returns a `knitr_kable` object.