# How to make sparklines in R Rmd to pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra, sparklines

in my Rmd to pdf, I want to have sparklines in a table. For an example that works in Rmd to html, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54578219/6170807. The build-in histograms and boxplots in kableExtra work fine in Rmd to pdf, but I want to have a line graph, not a histogram or boxplot. Anyone a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I understand you want Rmd to PDF, but sometimes the best option to get what you want may have to be to render it to HTML and then Print to pdf from the browser

Comment: That would be an option for a single document, but this will be part of a batch job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic example. We simply create a plot for each row/group and save it. In the table we add the latex code to the corresponding plot. Its up to you how to style and format the plots. You could check the source code of kableExtra to learn from how histograms and boxplots are implemented.

Another option would be to use `pagedown` to render paged HTML reports and print them using `pagedown::chrome_print` or manually through your browser. That way you can use the HTML sparkline approach.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, include=F}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(Country = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 5), 
                 Year = c(rep(2000, 3), rep(2001, 3), rep(2002, 3), rep(2003, 3), rep(2004, 3)),
                 Value = sample(1000:2000, size = 15))



df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  do({
    p <- ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Value)) + 
      geom_line(size = 5, color = ifelse(tail(.$Value, n = 1) < head(.$Value, n = 1), "firebrick3", "springgreen")) + 
      geom_line(size = 2.5, color = ifelse(tail(.$Value, n = 1) < head(.$Value, n = 1), "firebrick", "springgreen3")) + 
      theme_void()
    ggsave(p, filename = paste0("fig", unique(.$Country), ".pdf"), width = 4, height = 1.25)
    invisible(.)
  })


df <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Value) %>%
  mutate(Sparkline = paste0("\\raisebox{-.5\\height}{\\includegraphics[width=2cm]{fig", Country, ".pdf}}"))
```

```{r, echo  = F}
knitr::kable(df, escape = F)
```
````

[image]